# Errors with Gradients in ActionScript

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, vector-graphics

I am currently receiving the following errors:

> Scene 1, Layer 'Layer 1', Frame 1, Line 172    1119: Access of possibly undefined property joints through a reference with static type flash.display:GraphicsGradientFill.
>
> ---
>
> Scene 1, Layer 'Layer 1', Frame 1, Line 173    1067: Implicit coercion of a value of type flash.display:GraphicsSolidFill to an unrelated type Array.

When trying to create gradients like this:

```
import flash.display.JointStyle;

var stroke:GraphicsGradientFill = new GraphicsGradientFill();
stroke.joints = JointStyle.MITER;
stroke.alphas = new GraphicsSolidFill(0x102020, 1);

var fill:GraphicsGradientFill = new GraphicsGradientFill();
fill.colors = [0x0000FF, 0xEEFFEE];
fill.matrix = new Matrix();
fill.matrix.createGradientBox(70, 70, Math.PI / 2);

var path:GraphicsPath = new GraphicsPath(new Vector.<int>(), new Vector.<Number>);
path.commands.push(1, 2, 2);
path.data.push(125, 0, 50, 100, 175, 0);

var drawing:Vector.<IGraphicsData> = new Vector.<IGraphicsData>();
drawing.push(stroke, fill, path);

graphics.drawGraphicsData(drawing);
```

**What is causing these errors?**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try:

```
import flash.display.JointStyle;

JointStyle.MITER
```

**Edit:** Change `stroke.joints = JoinStyle.MITER;` => `stroke.joints = JointStyle.MITER;`

**Edit for new errors:**

`GraphicsGradientFill` does not have a property `joints` and the `alphas` property expects an array. I think maybe you are looking for `GraphicsStroke` instead of `GraphicsGradientFill` for the variable `stroke`?

Comment: I already `import flash.display.JointStyle;` as u can see on top of my code block

Comment: @HalilÇakar ...with emphasis on the `t` in Join**t**Style.MITER

Comment: OMG :( long hour work get me this thx man but i still get other 2 error

Comment: @HalilÇakar feel free to accept this and create new questions if you need help with the other errors.